# how let addon works on firefox builtin-pages?

Tags: firefox, browser-addons

firefox limits the addon activities only work on normal page, but not buildin pages, e.g. `setting` page or `default new page` or `error pages(like 404)`

how can let addons work on any pages including the firefox builtin page?

Comment: It would be a security vulnerability if you could.

Comment: i think i can take the risk :) @paa

Comment: Are you willing to take the risk of *every* addon author being able to change builtin pages like these you mentioned?

Comment: `yes`, i think it is what i wish in my case, so is there a way? @paa

Comment: It is possible with a special kind of extensions, implementing their own experimental api. Due to security concerns (experimental apis can do pretty much anything), these extensions can be installed only on Firefox Nightly and Firefox Developer Edition.

Answer (score 0):

You may tailor your default new page as described in the articles

- [Customize your New Tab page to hide or display content](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/customize-your-new-tab-page)
- [Customize items on your Firefox New Tab page](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/customize-items-on-firefox-new-tab-page)

Most of the work is done in *Settings > Home* :

---

[image]

---

You can't customize the error pages (like 404), since these are created
by the website you are addressing, so each site has its own error pages.